# searching for number in a range in solr

Tags: solr

One of my fields in solr is a `"score"` which is a decimal number between 0 and 1.

How can I return all data that is in a particular score range?

e.g. return all documents with a score in the range `0.1-0.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A legacy numeric field type that encodes "Float" values as simple
> Strings. This class should not be used except by people with existing
> indexes that contain numeric values indexed as Strings. New schemas
> should use TrieFloatField. Field values will sort numerically, but
> Range Queries (and other features that rely on numeric ranges) will
> not work as expected: values will be evaluated in unicode String
> order, not numeric order.

[float field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_4/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/FloatField.html)

Use the below fieldtype for your field.

```
<field name="score" type="tfloat" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Make sure to re-index after changing the schema and then try below range queries.

```
&fq=score:[0.1 TO 0.2]
```

Comment: TrieFloatFields are deprecated - use the `FloatPointField` instead these days, unless there's a specific reason for using the trie version. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html#field-types-included-with-solr